# I want to split this into two functions

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, functions, google-maps

This code i will add below is for Custom Fields for Custom Post Type and GMap for Custom Post Type.

Currently both are pulled by this function.

I want to seperate both. One for Custom Fields and One for Map.

Here is the Code:

---

```
add_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection','detail_fields_colletion');
/*
Name : detail_fields_colletion
Desc : Return the collection for detail/single page
*/
function detail_fields_colletion()
{
global $wpdb,$post,$detail_post_type;
$detail_post_type = $post->post_type;
if(isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid'])
{
    $cus_post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['pid']);
    $PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
    $PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
    $single_pos_id = $_REQUEST['pid'];
}
else
{   $cus_post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
    $PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
    $PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
    $single_pos_id = $post->ID;
}
$heading_type = fetch_heading_per_post_type($cus_post_type);
remove_all_actions('posts_where');
$post_query = null;
if(count($heading_type) > 0)
  { 
    foreach($heading_type as $_heading_type)
     {
        $args = 
        array( 'post_type' => 'custom_fields',
        'posts_per_page' => -1  ,
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'meta_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'post_type_'.$cus_post_type.'',
                'value' => $cus_post_type,
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'=> 'text'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'show_on_page',
                'value' =>  array('user_side','both_side'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'is_active',
                'value' =>  '1',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'heading_type',
                'value' =>  $_heading_type,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'show_on_detail',
                'value' =>  '1',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        ),
            'meta_key' => 'sort_order',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_value_num'=>'sort_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'                
        );
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $post_meta_info = $post_query;
    $suc_post = get_post($single_pos_id);

            if($post_meta_info->have_posts())
              {
                echo "<div class='grid02 rc_rightcol clearfix'>";
                echo "<ul class='list'>";                   
                  $i=0;
                while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();
                    $field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true);

                    if($i==0)
                    {
                        if($post->post_name!='post_excerpt' && $post->post_name!='post_content' && $post->post_name!='post_title' && $post->post_name!='post_images' && $post->post_name!='post_category')
                        {
                            if($_heading_type == "[#taxonomy_name#]"){
                                echo "<li><h2>";_e(ucfirst($PostTypeLabelName),DOMAIN);echo ' '; _e("Information",DOMAIN);echo "</h2></li>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<li><h2>".$_heading_type."</h2></li>";  
                            }   
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }

                        if(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))
                          { 
                            if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'multicheckbox')
                              {
                                $_value = "";
                                foreach(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true) as $value)
                                 {
                                    $_value .= $value.",";
                                 }
                                 echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".substr($_value,0,-1)."</p></li>";
                              }else if($field_type =='radio' || $field_type =='select'){

                                    $options = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID,"option_values",true));
                                    $options_title = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID,"option_title",true));

                                    for($i=0; $i<= count($options); $i++){
                                         $val = $options[$i];
                                        if(trim($val) == trim(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))){ 
                                            $val_label = $options_title[$i];

                                        }
                                    }

                                    if($val_label ==''){ $val_label = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true); } // if title not set then display the value

                                    echo "<li><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".$val_label."</p></li>";


                              }
                            else
                             {
                                 if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'ctype',true) == 'upload')
                                 {
                                    echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> Click here to download File <a href=".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true).">Download</a></p></li>";
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true)."</p></li>";
                                 }
                             }
                          }                         
                        if($post->post_name == 'post_excerpt' && $suc_post->post_excerpt!='')
                         {
                            $suc_post_excerpt = $suc_post->post_excerpt;
                            ?>
                                 <li>
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="twelve columns">
                                         <div class="title_space">
                                             <div class="title-container">
                                                 <h1><?php _e('Post Excerpt',DOMAIN);?></h1>
                                                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                             </div>
                                             <?php echo $suc_post_excerpt;?>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 </li>
                            <?php
                         }

                        if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'geo_map')
                         {
                            $add_str = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'address',true);
                            $geo_latitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_latitude',true);
                            $geo_longitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_longitude',true);
                            $map_view = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'map_view',true);                              
                         }       
                endwhile;wp_reset_query();
                echo "</ul>";
                echo "</div>";
              }     
       }
  }
 else
  {     
    $args = 
    array( 'post_type' => 'custom_fields',
    'posts_per_page' => -1  ,
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_type_'.$cus_post_type.'',
            'value' => $cus_post_type,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'=> 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'is_active',
            'value' =>  '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'show_on_detail',
            'value' =>  '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
        'meta_key' => 'sort_order',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );              
    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $post_meta_info = $post_query;
    $suc_post = get_post($single_pos_id);               
    if($post_meta_info->have_posts())
    {   
        $i=0;
        /*Display the post_detail gheading only one time also with if any custom field create. */
        while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();    
            if($i==0)
            if($post->post_name != 'post_excerpt' && $post->post_name != 'post_content' && $post->post_name != 'post_title' && $post->post_name != 'post_images' && $post->post_name != 'post_category')
            {
                echo '<div class="title-container clearfix">';  
                //echo '<h1>'.POST_DETAIL.'</h1>';
                $CustomFieldHeading = apply_filters('CustomFieldsHeadingTitle',POST_DETAIL);

                if(function_exists('icl_register_string')){
                    icl_register_string(DOMAIN,$CustomFieldHeading,$CustomFieldHeading);
                }

                if(function_exists('icl_t')){
                    $CustomFieldHeading1 = icl_t(DOMAIN,$CustomFieldHeading,$CustomFieldHeading);
                }else{
                    $CustomFieldHeading1 = __($CustomFieldHeading,DOMAIN); 
                }
                echo '<h3>'.$CustomFieldHeading1.'</h3>';

                echo '</div>';
                $i++;
            }           
        endwhile;wp_reset_query();  //Finish this while loop for display POST_DETAIL            
          ?>              
    <?php echo "<div class='grid02 rc_rightcol clearfix'>";
            echo "<ul class='list'>";
            if($_heading_type!="")          
                echo "<h3>".$_heading_type."</h3>";

        while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();                
                if(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))
                  {
                    if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'multicheckbox')
                      {
                        foreach(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true) as $value)
                         {
                            $_value .= $value.",";
                         }
                         echo "<li><p class='tevolution_field_title'>".$post->post_title.": </p> <p class='tevolution_field_value'> ".substr($_value,0,-1)."</p></li>";
                      }
                    else
                     {
                         echo "<li><p class='tevolution_field_title'>".$post->post_title.": </p> <p class='tevolution_field_value'> ".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true)."</p></li>";
                     }
                  }                         
                if($post->post_name == 'post_excerpt' && $suc_post->post_excerpt!="")
                 {
                    $suc_post_excerpt = $suc_post->post_excerpt;
                    ?>
                       <li>
                       <div class="row">
                          <div class="twelve columns">
                               <div class="title_space">
                                   <div class="title-container">
                                       <h1><?php _e('Post Excerpt');?></h1>
                                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                   </div>
                                   <?php echo $suc_post_excerpt;?>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       </li>
              <?php
                 }

                if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'geo_map')
                 {
                    $add_str = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'address',true);
                    $geo_latitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_latitude',true);
                    $geo_longitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_longitude',true);                                
                 }

        endwhile;wp_reset_query();
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</div>";
      }
  }
    if(isset($suc_post_con)):
    do_action('templ_before_post_content');/*Add action for before the post content. */?> 
         <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                 <div class="title_space">
                     <div class="title-container">
                         <h1><?php _e('Post Description', DOMAIN);?></h1>
                      </div>
                     <?php echo $suc_post_con;?>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    <?php do_action('templ_after_post_content'); /*Add Action for after the post content. */
    endif;      
        $tmpdata = get_option('templatic_settings');    
        $show_map='';
        if(isset($tmpdata['map_detail_page']) && $tmpdata['map_detail_page']=='yes')
            $show_map=$tmpdata['map_detail_page'];
        if(isset($add_str) && $add_str != '')
        {
        ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="title_space">
                    <div class="title-container">
                        <h1><?php _e('Map',DOMAIN); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <p><strong><?php _e('Location : '); echo $add_str;?></strong></p>
                </div>

                   <?php if($geo_latitude && $geo_longitude ):?>
                                                                 <!-- Location Map-->
                    <div id="location_map">
                          <div class="google_map" id="detail_google_map_id"> 
                            <?php include_once ('google_map_detail.php');?> 
                          </div>                                 <!-- google map #end -->
                    </div>

                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        <?php }

}
/* EOF */
```

---

And i call using

```
        <!--Custom field collection do action -->
        <?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection');  ?>
```

### in single-places.php

Please help me seperate Custom fields from Map and create function for each to call in the single-places.php seperately

Comment: Did you try separating it? What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: i dont know how to seperate the map and custome fields section. if you know please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate it into two functions by using following code :

```
<?php

add_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection','custom_fields_colletion');

/*
Name : custom_fields_colletion
Desc : Return the custom fields collection for detail/single page
*/
function custom_fields_colletion()
{
global $wpdb,$post,$detail_post_type;
$detail_post_type = $post->post_type;
if(isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid'])
{
$cus_post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['pid']);
$PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
$PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
$single_pos_id = $_REQUEST['pid'];
}
else
{   
$cus_post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
$PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
$PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
$single_pos_id = $post->ID;
}
$heading_type = fetch_heading_per_post_type($cus_post_type);
remove_all_actions('posts_where');
$post_query = null;
if(count($heading_type) > 0)
{ 
foreach($heading_type as $_heading_type)
 {
    $args =
    array( 'post_type' => 'custom_fields',
    'posts_per_page' => -1  ,
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_type_'.$cus_post_type.'',
            'value' => $cus_post_type,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'=> 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'show_on_page',
            'value' =>  array('user_side','both_side'),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'is_active',
            'value' =>  '1',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'heading_type',
            'value' =>  $_heading_type,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'show_on_detail',
            'value' =>  '1',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
        'meta_key' => 'sort_order',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_value_num'=>'sort_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

$post_meta_info = $post_query;
$suc_post = get_post($single_pos_id);

        if($post_meta_info->have_posts())
          {
            echo "<div class='grid02 rc_rightcol clearfix'>";
            echo "<ul class='list'>";
              $i=0;
            while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();
                $field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true);

                if($i==0)
                {
                    if($post->post_name!='post_excerpt' && $post->post_name!='post_content' && $post->post_name!='post_title' && $post->post_name!='post_images' && $post->post_name!='post_category')
                    {
                        if($_heading_type == "[#taxonomy_name#]"){
                            echo "<li><h2>";_e(ucfirst($PostTypeLabelName),DOMAIN);echo ' '; _e("Information",DOMAIN);echo "</h2></li>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<li><h2>".$_heading_type."</h2></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
                }

                    if(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))
                      {
                        if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'multicheckbox')
                          {
                            $_value = "";
                            foreach(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true) as $value)
                             {
                                $_value .= $value.",";
                             }
                             echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".substr($_value,0,-1)."</p></li>";
                          }else if($field_type =='radio' || $field_type =='select'){

                                $options = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID,"option_values",true));
                                $options_title = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID,"option_title",true));

                                for($i=0; $i<= count($options); $i++){
                                     $val = $options[$i];
                                    if(trim($val) == trim(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))){
                                        $val_label = $options_title[$i];

                                    }
                                }

                                if($val_label ==''){ $val_label = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true); } // if title not set then display the value

                                echo "<li><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".$val_label."</p></li>";


                          }
                        else
                         {
                             if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'ctype',true) == 'upload')
                             {
                                echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> Click here to download File <a href=".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true).">Download</a></p></li>";
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 echo "<li class='".$post->post_name."'><p>".$post->post_title." : </p> <p> ".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true)."</p></li>";
                             }
                         }
                      }
                    if($post->post_name == 'post_excerpt' && $suc_post->post_excerpt!='')
                     {
                        $suc_post_excerpt = $suc_post->post_excerpt;
                        ?>
                             <li>
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="twelve columns">
                                     <div class="title_space">
                                         <div class="title-container">
                                             <h1><?php _e('Post Excerpt',DOMAIN);?></h1>
                                             <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                         </div>
                                         <?php echo $suc_post_excerpt;?>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             </li>
                        <?php
                     }

                    if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'geo_map')
                     {
                        $add_str = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'address',true);
                        $geo_latitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_latitude',true);
                        $geo_longitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_longitude',true);
                        $map_view = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'map_view',true);
                     }
            endwhile;wp_reset_query();
            echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";
          }
   }
}

if(isset($suc_post_con)):
do_action('templ_before_post_content');/*Add action for before the post content. */?>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
             <div class="title_space">
                 <div class="title-container">
                     <h1><?php _e('Post Description', DOMAIN);?></h1>
                  </div>
                 <?php echo $suc_post_con;?>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
<?php do_action('templ_after_post_content'); /*Add Action for after the post content. */
endif;
}


add_action('tmpl_detail_page_gmap_collection','gmap_colletion');

/*
Name : gmap_colletion
Desc : Return the gmap collection for detail/single page
*/
function gmap_colletion()
{
global $wpdb,$post,$detail_post_type;
$detail_post_type = $post->post_type;
if(isset($_REQUEST['pid']) && $_REQUEST['pid'])
{
$cus_post_type = get_post_type($_REQUEST['pid']);
$PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
$PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
$single_pos_id = $_REQUEST['pid'];
}
else
{   $cus_post_type = get_post_type($post->ID);
$PostTypeObject = get_post_type_object($cus_post_type);
$PostTypeLabelName = $PostTypeObject->labels->name;
$single_pos_id = $post->ID;
}
$heading_type = fetch_heading_per_post_type($cus_post_type);
remove_all_actions('posts_where');
$post_query = null;

if(count($heading_type) <= 0){
$args =
array( 'post_type' => 'custom_fields',
'posts_per_page' => -1  ,
'post_status' => array('publish'),
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'post_type_'.$cus_post_type.'',
        'value' => $cus_post_type,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'=> 'text'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'is_active',
        'value' =>  '1',
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'show_on_detail',
        'value' =>  '1',
        'compare' => '='
    )
),
    'meta_key' => 'sort_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$post_query = new WP_Query($args);
$post_meta_info = $post_query;
$suc_post = get_post($single_pos_id);
if($post_meta_info->have_posts())
{
    $i=0;
    /*Display the post_detail gheading only one time also with if any custom field create. */
    while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();
        if($i==0)
        if($post->post_name != 'post_excerpt' && $post->post_name != 'post_content' && $post->post_name != 'post_title' && $post->post_name != 'post_images' && $post->post_name != 'post_category')
        {
            echo '<div class="title-container clearfix">';
            //echo '<h1>'.POST_DETAIL.'</h1>';
            $CustomFieldHeading = apply_filters('CustomFieldsHeadingTitle',POST_DETAIL);

            if(function_exists('icl_register_string')){
                icl_register_string(DOMAIN,$CustomFieldHeading,$CustomFieldHeading);
            }

            if(function_exists('icl_t')){
                $CustomFieldHeading1 = icl_t(DOMAIN,$CustomFieldHeading,$CustomFieldHeading);
            }else{
                $CustomFieldHeading1 = __($CustomFieldHeading,DOMAIN);
            }
            echo '<h3>'.$CustomFieldHeading1.'</h3>';

            echo '</div>';
            $i++;
        }
    endwhile;wp_reset_query();  //Finish this while loop for display POST_DETAIL
      ?>
<?php echo "<div class='grid02 rc_rightcol clearfix'>";
        echo "<ul class='list'>";
        if($_heading_type!="")
            echo "<h3>".$_heading_type."</h3>";

    while ($post_meta_info->have_posts()) : $post_meta_info->the_post();
            if(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true))
              {
                if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'multicheckbox')
                  {
                    foreach(get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true) as $value)
                     {
                        $_value .= $value.",";
                     }
                     echo "<li><p class='tevolution_field_title'>".$post->post_title.": </p> <p class='tevolution_field_value'> ".substr($_value,0,-1)."</p></li>";
                  }
                else
                 {
                     echo "<li><p class='tevolution_field_title'>".$post->post_title.": </p> <p class='tevolution_field_value'> ".get_post_meta($single_pos_id,$post->post_name,true)."</p></li>";
                 }
              }
            if($post->post_name == 'post_excerpt' && $suc_post->post_excerpt!="")
             {
                $suc_post_excerpt = $suc_post->post_excerpt;
                ?>
                   <li>
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="twelve columns">
                           <div class="title_space">
                               <div class="title-container">
                                   <h1><?php _e('Post Excerpt');?></h1>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
                               </div>
                               <?php echo $suc_post_excerpt;?>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   </li>
          <?php
             }

            if(get_post_meta($post->ID,"ctype",true) == 'geo_map')
             {
                $add_str = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'address',true);
                $geo_latitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_latitude',true);
                $geo_longitude = get_post_meta($single_pos_id,'geo_longitude',true);
             }

    endwhile;wp_reset_query();
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
}

    $tmpdata = get_option('templatic_settings');
    $show_map='';
    if(isset($tmpdata['map_detail_page']) && $tmpdata['map_detail_page']=='yes')
        $show_map=$tmpdata['map_detail_page'];
    if(isset($add_str) && $add_str != '')
    {
    ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="title_space">
                <div class="title-container">
                    <h1><?php _e('Map',DOMAIN); ?></h1>
                </div>
                <p><strong><?php _e('Location : '); echo $add_str;?></strong></p>
            </div>

               <?php if($geo_latitude && $geo_longitude ):?>
                                                             <!-- Location Map-->
                <div id="location_map">
                      <div class="google_map" id="detail_google_map_id">
                        <?php include_once ('google_map_detail.php');?>
                      </div>                                 <!-- google map #end -->
                </div>

            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    <?php }

}
?>
```

and you can call it using :

```
<!--Custom field collection do action -->
<?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection');  ?>

<!--GMap collection do action -->
<?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_gmap_collection');  ?>
```

Comment: Its not Working.

Comment: '<?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection'); ?>'
shows Custom Fields Twice with Map and this one     

    '<?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_gmap_collection');  ?>' doesnt show anything

Comment: Have you added the two functions above in the code? Can you show me your whole code by pasting it in pastebin?

Comment: Please Help Again

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RvDURBBe

Comment: i have added the code for the function in the pastebin, check above link

Comment: Have you not added my code?

Comment: you want the whole php code or only the section which calls the function

Comment: The template files where you have added the code.

Comment: i will add the whole taxonomy-functions.php in the pastebin please check and tell me where should i add your code. because currently i tried adding your code above and below the code i have added in the first time. i will send the link to pastebin here http://pastebin.com/GvMjS2AV

Comment: this is my page link which is related to this php http://cludoc.com/insane/places/extreme-sports-bar/                     You can See Information and Map Sections, currently these both sections are pulled by this code                                         <!--Custom field collection do action -->
        <?php do_action('tmpl_detail_page_custom_fields_collection');  ?>

Comment: You should add this code in functions.php file

Comment: actually the custom post type functions is taxonomy-functions.php, i will try adding in the themes functions.php also.

Comment: check this link again  http://cludoc.com/insane/places/extreme-sports-bar/

now i am getting Info, Map, Info Again.  I added the code into functions.php and called in the single-places.php file i have added the single-places.php file on pastebin here http://pastebin.com/c9dN1Sxw

Comment: Vinod i think the problem is that Custom Fields are fine, Map is also added as a custom Field called Geo_Map. I think its causing the problem. i think we need to seperate both the functions for map as well as all other custom fields. do you want me to give the custom field plugin called tevolution to check out and make the changes. would be of great help

Comment: would you like to come on skype, if its not trouble

Comment: Hi vinod are you there